# Interesting bit mask formation

Tags: c, bitmask

I came across these bit mask formations but wonder the logic behind them

```
MASK_01010101 = ((unsigned int) (-1))/3
MASK_00110011 = ((unsigned int) (-1))/5
MASK_00001111 = ((unsigned int) (-1))/17
```

Edit: Thanks Michael. I edited the last one

Comment: Start by reading about [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), then you will understand what `(unsigned int) -1` does.

Comment: These definitions are horrible! The name of the constant already has the bit pattern (e.g. `01010101`), it might have as well set it to `0x55` instead of calculating in a non-standard way.

Answer (score 2):

How beatiful! But last one is wrong ((unsigned int)(-1))/7 = b00100100!

For those who interested in **full version of 8-bit masks** see this [link](http://codepad.org/Eu4bKlg7) at codepad.org.

Comment: No it isn't — it's b1001001. I think `(-1))/17` is what was intended

Comment: Thanks for comment! But 1001001 is also wrong. It should be MASK_00100100= ((unsigned int)(-1)/7).

Answer (score 1):

If you cast `-1` to an unsigned integer type, it wraps around to the maximum (positive) value the type can represent. In other words, all 1's in binary.

The division operation in each case maybe becomes a bit clearer when you consider the binary form:

- 3 -> 11
- 5 -> 101
- 17 -> 10001

Dividing all 1's by these bit patterns gives you one of the patterns shown in your `MASK_*` names. (`unsigned int` is generally more than 8 bits though, so the actual patterns will be longer.)

Answer (score 0):

the author did not have clarity or efficiency in mind when he/she wrote that. They were just showing off or purposefully obfuscating the code.

Comment: _showing off_?  Really?  Your conclusion makes gross assumptions.

Comment: Without knowledge of the author assumptions are the only possible response to this question. It could more easily have been written in a readable manner. If the author's intent was clear this question would not have been necessary.